# Prove that there exists a natural number m such that each eigenvalue of A is an m-th root of unity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let$ A$ and $X$ be invertible complex matrices such that $XAX^{−1} = A^2$
.
Prove that there exists a natural number m such that each eigenvalue
of A is an m-th root of unity.

i was taking the set $\{ \lambda , \lambda^1 , \lambda^{2} , \lambda^{3}, \dots, \lambda^{m} \}$

$\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $ A$

I don't  know how  to show  that there exists a natural number m such that each eigenvalue of A is an m-th root of unity.

Pliz help  me

Thanks in advance

Comment: how it is duplicate  my Question is diifferents ???

Comment: Your question is the $k=2$ case of the previous one.